# how to handle Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT when my marker jump out from my fence

Tags: java, android

When I set condition for geofence Exit its work properly but after some time marker is jump out from fence so tell me that how to handle jumping of marker..

```
if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    int geofenceTransitions = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

                    if (geofenceTransitions == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
                        Log.d("EXIT", "You are exit");
                        Toast.makeText(GeoFenceTransitionIntentService.this, "u r exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        List<Geofence> triggerdGeoFencesList = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

                        //Getting the location that triggered the geofence transition.
                        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(GeoFenceTransitionIntentService.this, geofenceTransitions, triggerdGeoFencesList);

                        sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
                        Log.d(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
                        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy , hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                        String st_date = format.format(date);
                        Map<String, String> timestamp = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;


                    } else if (geofenceTransitions == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {

                        Log.d("ENTER", "You are enter back in office");
                        Toast.makeText(GeoFenceTransitionIntentService.this, "\"You are enter back in office\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, 1000 * 1 * 60);
```